# I cannot connect to my AWS EC2 instance via SSH clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, terminal

Please help me! After reboot my ec2 server, I cannot connect to new AWS EC2 instance via SSH clients

Just print

'Permission denied (publickey).'

I googled really hard. Most people said that it is about problem of username. 3 hours ago, I used 'ec2-user' as my username. Just minutes ago, I also used username 'ec2-user'. But, after reboot my ec2 server I cannot connect with my username 'ec2-user'. What the hell?

Please help me T.T

User: tried "root" and also "ec2-user", "admin" but still I cannot connect

Using .pem keypair that AWS generated and I downloaded

Confirmed security group and Key Pair Name on instance

Instance: ec2-52-78-40-153.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
AMI ID: amzn-ami-hvm-2016.09.0.20161028-x86_64-gp2 (ami-983ce8f6)
OS: OS X el capitan

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question belongs in serverfault.com community, not here. This is a forum to answer questions of those who have written programming code and are experiencing a unique and specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you are receiving `Permission denied (publickey)` means that you have correct network connectivity to your instance and the Security Group is permitting SSH traffic. Therefore, the problem lies with authentication.

Some things to check:

- Use `ssh -v` to turn on verbose debug information
- Select the instance in the Amazon EC2 Management Console and look for the **Key Pair name**. Confirm that it matches the name of the file you are using. (The filename itself is irrelevant, but will be accurate unless files were renamed.)
- If you have added/modified users on the instance, you might need to use a different username. If you have not changed users, then `ec2-user` is the correct username.

If you are unable to connect, then you can follow the directions from pages such as:

- [How to Recover an Unreachable Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598)
- [Recovering a corrupted EC2 instance](https://amalgjose.com/2016/04/05/recovering-a-corrupted-ec2-instance/)
- [Replace a lost Key Pair on an EC2 instance](http://blog.celingest.com/en/2013/11/14/replace-lost-keypair-ec2-instance/)

Basically, the steps are:

- **Stop** the instance
- **Detach** the boot volume (remember the device identifier, eg `/dev/sdf`)
- **Attach** the instance to another Amazon EC2 Linux instance
- Navigate to the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh` directory and confirm that the correct **public key** is inserted into the `authorized_keys` file. If desired, create a new keypair and put the public key in that file.
- **Detach** the volume
- **Reattach** the volume to the original instance
- **Start** the original instance and attempt to login

Basically, Linux will check the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the home directory of the user being logged-in. If additional users have been created, put their keys in the same location within their home directories.